# Golang fasthttp very slow with request

Tags: rest, http, go, fasthttp

I am building a Rest API with [fasthttp](https://github.com/valyala/fasthttp) package. I have a test route that I am using to measure performance:

```
package main

import (
    "github.com/valyala/fasthttp"
    "runtime"
)

func main() {

    runtime.GOMAXPROCS(8)
    m := func(ctx *fasthttp.RequestCtx) {
        switch string(ctx.Path()) {
        case "/test":
            test(ctx)
        default:
            ctx.Error("not found", fasthttp.StatusNotFound)
        }
    }

    fasthttp.ListenAndServe(":80", m)
}

func test(ctx *fasthttp.RequestCtx) {
    println("HERE")
}
```

If I send a request to this route it takes over 10 seconds to get to the `println("HERE")` in the test function.

I have built a comparable endpoint in `Node.js` and this exact same function and route takes 126 milliseconds.
Why in the world does it take so long just to call the function that this route points to in Go?

Comment: I've just tested with your exact code, it takes almost no time (below 1 second) in reaching the `println("HERE")`. How excactly did you setup your test?

Comment: try my samples and post(add comment) the code (2) output

Answer (score 4):

For me it takes just 7.9454545s for 100000 `http.Head` (79.454545us per `http.Head`, with just 2 Core CPU in 77% Load when running these 1 and 2 codes).

You don't need `runtime.GOMAXPROCS(8)`, and use `fmt.Println()` instead of `println()`

1- Try  this:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"

    "github.com/valyala/fasthttp"
)

func main() {
    m := func(ctx *fasthttp.RequestCtx) {
        switch string(ctx.Path()) {
        case "/test":
            test(ctx)
        default:
            fmt.Println(i)
            ctx.Error("not found", fasthttp.StatusNotFound)
        }
    }
    fasthttp.ListenAndServe(":80", m)
}

func test(ctx *fasthttp.RequestCtx) {
    i++
}

var i int = 0
```

output:

```
100000
```

2- With this Get:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "net/http"
    "time"
)

func main() {
    t := time.Now()
    for i := 0; i < 100000; i++ {
        read(`http://localhost/test`)
    }
    fmt.Println(time.Since(t))
    read(`http://localhost/`)
}

func read(url string) {
    _, err := http.Head(url)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
    }
}
```

output:

```
7.9454545s
```

---

3- Output of [This code](https://play.golang.org/p/HU-R3RFSct):

```
8.6294936s
```